# buildfarm fails for noetic with KeyError: libcurlpp-dev

Tags: ros, buildfarm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We are trying to release the packages in [pf_lidar_ros_driver](https://github.com/PepperlFuchs/pf_lidar_ros_driver) for `melodic` and `noetic`. We have been able to release for `melodic` successfully in the past and even the [latest job](https://build.ros.org/job/Mbin_ubv8_uBv8__pf_driver__ubuntu_bionic_arm64__binary/21/) was successful. However the [job for noetic](https://build.ros.org/job/Nbin_dbv8_dBv8__pf_driver__debian_buster_arm64__binary/3/) failed with the error:

```
Looking for the '.dsc' file of package 'ros-noetic-pf-driver' with version '1.2.0-1'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 297, in __getitem__
    rawpkg = self._cache[key]
KeyError: 'libcurlpp-dev'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/ros_buildfarm/scripts/release/create_binarydeb_task_generator.py", line 216, in <module>
    main()
  File "/tmp/ros_buildfarm/scripts/release/create_binarydeb_task_generator.py", line 92, in main
    apt_cache, debian_pkg_names)
  File "/tmp/ros_buildfarm/ros_buildfarm/common.py", line 175, in get_binary_package_versions
    pkg = apt_cache[debian_pkg_name]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 299, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError('The cache has no package named %r' % key)
KeyError: "The cache has no package named 'libcurlpp-dev'"
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Since `libcurlpp-dev` is not a ROS package and is present in [rosdistro](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/758f24e2bfc27f3ccb1ebaf5b273534596f18024/rosdep/base.yaml#L706), I am wondering what went wrong in case of `noetic`.

**Edit 1:** Among all the [builds](https://build.ros.org/job/Nbin_dbv8_dBv8__pf_driver__debian_buster_arm64__binary/3/search/?q=pf_driver&Jenkins-Crumb=d527155b2b2e3b0863a1f359a920bf20c9d140d3d730fb5ac10b1205853e4732), looks like it fails only for `debian buster`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400344/buildfarm-fails-for-noetic-with-keyerror:-libcurlpp-dev/) by [ipa-hsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26721/ipa-hsd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 150 on 2022-05-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Afaict, there is no `libcurlpp-dev` in the current `rosdep` [db](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/758f24e2bfc27f3ccb1ebaf5b273534596f18024/rosdep/base.yaml).

The only keys which contain the `libcurl` substring are `libcurl` and `libcurl-dev`.

`libcurlpp-dev` does not exist. Only `curlpp-dev` ([here](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/758f24e2bfc27f3ccb1ebaf5b273534596f18024/rosdep/base.yaml#L706-L711)).

Seeing the traceback though, it would appear this is not a problem with the `rosdep` side of things, but while actually installing packages (in this case the `.deb`): `curlpp-dev` maps to `libcurlpp-dev` for `debian`. According to [this](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libcurlpp-dev), that package only exists in `bullseye`, `bookworm` and `sid` (if you include Debian Unstable).

If it doesn't exist in other releases, the `curlpp-dev` key might have to be specialised further for the `debian` OS entry.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ipa-hsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26721/ipa-hsd/) on 2022-05-10**:
Yes we did use the keyword [curlpp-dev](https://github.com/PepperlFuchs/pf_lidar_ros_driver/blob/main/pf_driver/package.xml#L20). But for debian and ubuntu it gets resolved to `libcurlpp-dev`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-10**:
Yes, but you wrote:

> Since `libcurlpp-dev` is not a ROS package and is present in [rosdistro](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/758f24e2bfc27f3ccb1ebaf5b273534596f18024/rosdep/base.yaml#L706), [..]

which implied you believed it is a problem with `rosdep` somewhow.

**Comment by [ipa-hsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26721/ipa-hsd/) on 2022-05-10**:
That was my initial thought. But with my "edit 1", I realized it seems to be a problem with debian buster specifically.

**Comment by [ipa-hsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/26721/ipa-hsd/) on 2022-05-10**:
Yes agreed with your recent edit

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-10**:
That would still not make the build succeed of course.

Perhaps blacklisting the package for Buster would be an option.